# How to change product Image when variables are selected in Shop and Archive Pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use this hook to show variations on the shop page. However, the product image does not change when a variable is selected. It works on a Single product page. New to WordPress and PHP, I have thought woocommerce hooks work like a "copy and paste". Why is it not working for the shop page? How can it work for the shop page?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'show_production_variations_on_shop_page' );
function show_production_variations_on_shop_page() {

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
```

[image]

Comment: show_production_variations_on_shop_page() what is in there ? Also you cant mix hooks they are passing different args so some work for archives,categories etc other for cart other for single product. Also for variations WooCommerce uses JS. Either use plugin or debug. With current example there is nothing to help with.

Comment: Thanks @MartinMirchev After adding that, it shows the variations select box, qty field and add to cart button on shop page.

Comment: Like i said you cant just mix hooks - woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart will do the following - load depending on product type different function in your case will load this woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() where its built the variation product form. http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.6/files/includes-wc-template-functions/ . To update images you have to use either ajax or load all images and on change to update to the proper image. After that update add to cart button variables.

Comment: Thanks so much @MartinMirchev May I ask which template pages can I look at to have an idea of how the images are switched for variable products in Single product page?

Comment: If you cant debug that will be hard for you to solve it. You can look in to the js responsible for updating the image on variation select - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js. For template you should work with content-product.php and its hooks to output your variations and so on - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php

Comment: Thanks @MartinMirchev Appreciate the direction. It looks and sounds intimidating. Perhaps that's why the guides I found online don't work. The one that I posted is the closest and simplest, I assumed it is just a step away to make it work. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to dequeue woocommerce `add-to-cart-variation.js` from the shop page because we have to override from the plugin or theme. so you need to clone `add-to-cart-variation.js` and `enqueue` from your theme or your plugin wherever you are developing.

```
function add_custom_js(){
    
    if( is_shop() ){

        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

        $version = WC_VERSION;

        // Register the script
        wp_register_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/add-to-cart-variation.js', array( 'jquery', 'wp-util', 'jquery-blockui' ), $version );
         
        // Localize the script with new data
        
        $params = array(
            'wc_ajax_url'                      => WC_AJAX::get_endpoint( '%%endpoint%%' ),
            'i18n_no_matching_variations_text' => esc_attr__( 'Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'i18n_make_a_selection_text'       => esc_attr__( 'Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'i18n_unavailable_text'            => esc_attr__( 'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ),
        );

        wp_localize_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation', 'wc_add_to_cart_variation_params', $params );
         
        // Enqueued script with localized data.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_js', 9999, 1 );
```

create an `add-to-cart-variation.js` file in your active theme or your plugin wherever you are developing. ( I am `enqueueing` from theme )

Add below js code which is the same as woocommerce `add-to-cart-variation.js` but we have to modify it as per requirement.

```
/*global wc_add_to_cart_variation_params */
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    /**
     * VariationForm class which handles variation forms and attributes.
     */
    var VariationForm = function( $form ) {
        var self = this;

        self.$form                = $form;
        self.$attributeFields     = $form.find( '.variations select' );
        self.$singleVariation     = $form.find( '.single_variation' );
        self.$singleVariationWrap = $form.find( '.single_variation_wrap' );
        self.$resetVariations     = $form.find( '.reset_variations' );
        self.$product             = $form.closest( '.product' );
        self.variationData        = $form.data( 'product_variations' );
        self.useAjax              = false === self.variationData;
        self.xhr                  = false;
        self.loading              = true;

        // Initial state.
        self.$singleVariationWrap.show();
        self.$form.off( '.wc-variation-form' );

        // Methods.
        self.getChosenAttributes    = self.getChosenAttributes.bind( self );
        self.findMatchingVariations = self.findMatchingVariations.bind( self );
        self.isMatch                = self.isMatch.bind( self );
        self.toggleResetLink        = self.toggleResetLink.bind( self );

        // Events.
        $form.on( 'click.wc-variation-form', '.reset_variations', { variationForm: self }, self.onReset );
        $form.on( 'reload_product_variations', { variationForm: self }, self.onReload );
        $form.on( 'hide_variation', { variationForm: self }, self.onHide );
        $form.on( 'show_variation', { variationForm: self }, self.onShow );
        $form.on( 'reset_data', { variationForm: self }, self.onResetDisplayedVariation );
        $form.on( 'reset_image', { variationForm: self }, self.onResetImage );
        $form.on( 'change.wc-variation-form', '.variations select', { variationForm: self }, self.onChange );
        $form.on( 'found_variation.wc-variation-form', { variationForm: self }, self.onFoundVariation );
        $form.on( 'check_variations.wc-variation-form', { variationForm: self }, self.onFindVariation );
        $form.on( 'update_variation_values.wc-variation-form', { variationForm: self }, self.onUpdateAttributes );

        // Init after gallery.
        setTimeout( function() {
            $form.trigger( 'check_variations' );
            $form.trigger( 'wc_variation_form', self );
            self.loading = false;
        }, 100 );
    };

    /**
     * Reset all fields.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onReset = function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.data.variationForm.$attributeFields.val( '' ).trigger( 'change' );
        event.data.variationForm.$form.trigger( 'reset_data' );
    };

    /**
     * Reload variation data from the DOM.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onReload = function( event ) {
        var form           = event.data.variationForm;
        form.variationData = form.$form.data( 'product_variations' );
        form.useAjax       = false === form.variationData;
        form.$form.trigger( 'check_variations' );
    };

    /**
     * When a variation is hidden.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onHide = function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.data.variationForm.$form
            .find( '.single_add_to_cart_button' )
            .removeClass( 'wc-variation-is-unavailable' )
            .addClass( 'disabled wc-variation-selection-needed' );
        event.data.variationForm.$form
            .find( '.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart' )
            .removeClass( 'woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled' )
            .addClass( 'woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled' );
    };

    /**
     * When a variation is shown.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onShow = function( event, variation, purchasable ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( purchasable ) {
            event.data.variationForm.$form
                .find( '.single_add_to_cart_button' )
                .removeClass( 'disabled wc-variation-selection-needed wc-variation-is-unavailable' );
            event.data.variationForm.$form
                .find( '.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart' )
                .removeClass( 'woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled' )
                .addClass( 'woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled' );
        } else {
            event.data.variationForm.$form
                .find( '.single_add_to_cart_button' )
                .removeClass( 'wc-variation-selection-needed' )
                .addClass( 'disabled wc-variation-is-unavailable' );
            event.data.variationForm.$form
                .find( '.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart' )
                .removeClass( 'woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled' )
                .addClass( 'woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled' );
        }

        // If present, the media element library needs initialized on the variation description.
        if ( wp.mediaelement ) {
            event.data.variationForm.$form.find( '.wp-audio-shortcode, .wp-video-shortcode' )
                .not( '.mejs-container' )
                .filter(
                    function () {
                        return ! $( this ).parent().hasClass( 'mejs-mediaelement' );
                    }
                )
                .mediaelementplayer( wp.mediaelement.settings );
        }
    };

    /**
     * When displayed variation data is reset.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onResetDisplayedVariation = function( event ) {
        var form = event.data.variationForm;
        form.$product.find( '.product_meta' ).find( '.sku' ).wc_reset_content();
        form.$product
            .find( '.product_weight, .woocommerce-product-attributes-item--weight .woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value' )
            .wc_reset_content();
        form.$product
            .find( '.product_dimensions, .woocommerce-product-attributes-item--dimensions .woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value' )
            .wc_reset_content();
        form.$form.trigger( 'reset_image' );
        form.$singleVariation.slideUp( 200 ).trigger( 'hide_variation' );
    };

    /**
     * When the product image is reset.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onResetImage = function( event ) {
        event.data.variationForm.$form.wc_variations_image_update( false );
    };

    /**
     * Looks for matching variations for current selected attributes.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onFindVariation = function( event, chosenAttributes ) {
        var form              = event.data.variationForm,
            attributes        = 'undefined' !== typeof chosenAttributes ? chosenAttributes : form.getChosenAttributes(),
            currentAttributes = attributes.data;

        if ( attributes.count && attributes.count === attributes.chosenCount ) {
            if ( form.useAjax ) {
                if ( form.xhr ) {
                    form.xhr.abort();
                }
                form.$form.block( { message: null, overlayCSS: { background: '#fff', opacity: 0.6 } } );
                currentAttributes.product_id  = parseInt( form.$form.data( 'product_id' ), 10 );
                currentAttributes.custom_data = form.$form.data( 'custom_data' );
                form.xhr                      = $.ajax( {
                    url: wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'get_variation' ),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: currentAttributes,
                    success: function( variation ) {
                        if ( variation ) {
                            form.$form.trigger( 'found_variation', [ variation ] );
                        } else {
                            form.$form.trigger( 'reset_data' );
                            attributes.chosenCount = 0;

                            if ( ! form.loading ) {
                                form.$form
                                    .find( '.single_variation' )
                                    .after(
                                        '<p class="wc-no-matching-variations woocommerce-info">' +
                                        wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.i18n_no_matching_variations_text +
                                        '</p>'
                                    );
                                form.$form.find( '.wc-no-matching-variations' ).slideDown( 200 );
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        form.$form.unblock();
                    }
                } );
            } else {
                form.$form.trigger( 'update_variation_values' );

                var matching_variations = form.findMatchingVariations( form.variationData, currentAttributes ),
                    variation           = matching_variations.shift();

                if ( variation ) {
                    form.$form.trigger( 'found_variation', [ variation ] );
                } else {
                    form.$form.trigger( 'reset_data' );
                    attributes.chosenCount = 0;

                    if ( ! form.loading ) {
                        form.$form
                            .find( '.single_variation' )
                            .after(
                                '<p class="wc-no-matching-variations woocommerce-info">' +
                                wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.i18n_no_matching_variations_text +
                                '</p>'
                            );
                        form.$form.find( '.wc-no-matching-variations' ).slideDown( 200 );
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            form.$form.trigger( 'update_variation_values' );
            form.$form.trigger( 'reset_data' );
        }

        // Show reset link.
        form.toggleResetLink( attributes.chosenCount > 0 );
    };

    /**
     * Triggered when a variation has been found which matches all attributes.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onFoundVariation = function( event, variation ) {
        var form           = event.data.variationForm,
            $sku           = form.$product.find( '.product_meta' ).find( '.sku' ),
            $weight        = form.$product.find(
                '.product_weight, .woocommerce-product-attributes-item--weight .woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value'
            ),
            $dimensions    = form.$product.find(
                '.product_dimensions, .woocommerce-product-attributes-item--dimensions .woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value'
            ),
            $qty           = form.$singleVariationWrap.find( '.quantity' ),
            purchasable    = true,
            variation_id   = '',
            template       = false,
            $template_html = '';

        if ( variation.sku ) {
            $sku.wc_set_content( variation.sku );
        } else {
            $sku.wc_reset_content();
        }

        if ( variation.weight ) {
            $weight.wc_set_content( variation.weight_html );
        } else {
            $weight.wc_reset_content();
        }

        if ( variation.dimensions ) {
            // Decode HTML entities.
            $dimensions.wc_set_content( $.parseHTML( variation.dimensions_html )[0].data );
        } else {
            $dimensions.wc_reset_content();
        }

        form.$form.wc_variations_image_update( variation );

        if ( ! variation.variation_is_visible ) {
            template = wp_template( 'unavailable-variation-template' );
        } else {
            template     = wp_template( 'variation-template' );
            variation_id = variation.variation_id;
        }

        $template_html = template( {
            variation: variation
        } );
        $template_html = $template_html.replace( '/*<![CDATA[*/', '' );
        $template_html = $template_html.replace( '/*]]>*/', '' );

        form.$singleVariation.html( $template_html );
        form.$form.find( 'input[name="variation_id"], input.variation_id' ).val( variation.variation_id ).trigger( 'change' );

        // Hide or show qty input
        if ( variation.is_sold_individually === 'yes' ) {
            $qty.find( 'input.qty' ).val( '1' ).attr( 'min', '1' ).attr( 'max', '' ).trigger( 'change' );
            $qty.hide();
        } else {

            var $qty_input = $qty.find( 'input.qty' ),
                qty_val    = parseFloat( $qty_input.val() );

            if ( isNaN( qty_val ) ) {
                qty_val = variation.min_qty;
            } else {
                qty_val = qty_val > parseFloat( variation.max_qty ) ? variation.max_qty : qty_val;
                qty_val = qty_val < parseFloat( variation.min_qty ) ? variation.min_qty : qty_val;
            }

            $qty_input.attr( 'min', variation.min_qty ).attr( 'max', variation.max_qty ).val( qty_val ).trigger( 'change' );
            $qty.show();
        }

        // Enable or disable the add to cart button
        if ( ! variation.is_purchasable || ! variation.is_in_stock || ! variation.variation_is_visible ) {
            purchasable = false;
        }

        // Reveal
        if ( form.$singleVariation.text().trim() ) {
            form.$singleVariation.slideDown( 200 ).trigger( 'show_variation', [ variation, purchasable ] );
        } else {
            form.$singleVariation.show().trigger( 'show_variation', [ variation, purchasable ] );
        }
    };

    /**
     * Triggered when an attribute field changes.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onChange = function( event ) {
        var form = event.data.variationForm;

        form.$form.find( 'input[name="variation_id"], input.variation_id' ).val( '' ).trigger( 'change' );
        form.$form.find( '.wc-no-matching-variations' ).remove();

        if ( form.useAjax ) {
            form.$form.trigger( 'check_variations' );
        } else {
            form.$form.trigger( 'woocommerce_variation_select_change' );
            form.$form.trigger( 'check_variations' );
        }

        // Custom event for when variation selection has been changed
        form.$form.trigger( 'woocommerce_variation_has_changed' );
    };

    /**
     * Escape quotes in a string.
     * @param {string} string
     * @return {string}
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.addSlashes = function( string ) {
        string = string.replace( /'/g, '\\\'' );
        string = string.replace( /"/g, '\\\"' );
        return string;
    };

    /**
     * Updates attributes in the DOM to show valid values.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.onUpdateAttributes = function( event ) {
        var form              = event.data.variationForm,
            attributes        = form.getChosenAttributes(),
            currentAttributes = attributes.data;

        if ( form.useAjax ) {
            return;
        }

        // Loop through selects and disable/enable options based on selections.
        form.$attributeFields.each( function( index, el ) {
            var current_attr_select     = $( el ),
                current_attr_name       = current_attr_select.data( 'attribute_name' ) || current_attr_select.attr( 'name' ),
                show_option_none        = $( el ).data( 'show_option_none' ),
                option_gt_filter        = ':gt(0)',
                attached_options_count  = 0,
                new_attr_select         = $( '<select/>' ),
                selected_attr_val       = current_attr_select.val() || '',
                selected_attr_val_valid = true;

            // Reference options set at first.
            if ( ! current_attr_select.data( 'attribute_html' ) ) {
                var refSelect = current_attr_select.clone();

                refSelect.find( 'option' ).removeAttr( 'attached' ).prop( 'disabled', false ).prop( 'selected', false );

                // Legacy data attribute.
                current_attr_select.data(
                    'attribute_options',
                    refSelect.find( 'option' + option_gt_filter ).get()
                );
                current_attr_select.data( 'attribute_html', refSelect.html() );
            }

            new_attr_select.html( current_attr_select.data( 'attribute_html' ) );

            // The attribute of this select field should not be taken into account when calculating its matching variations:
            // The constraints of this attribute are shaped by the values of the other attributes.
            var checkAttributes = $.extend( true, {}, currentAttributes );

            checkAttributes[ current_attr_name ] = '';

            var variations = form.findMatchingVariations( form.variationData, checkAttributes );

            // Loop through variations.
            for ( var num in variations ) {
                if ( typeof( variations[ num ] ) !== 'undefined' ) {
                    var variationAttributes = variations[ num ].attributes;

                    for ( var attr_name in variationAttributes ) {
                        if ( variationAttributes.hasOwnProperty( attr_name ) ) {
                            var attr_val         = variationAttributes[ attr_name ],
                                variation_active = '';

                            if ( attr_name === current_attr_name ) {
                                if ( variations[ num ].variation_is_active ) {
                                    variation_active = 'enabled';
                                }

                                if ( attr_val ) {
                                    // Decode entities.
                                    attr_val = $( '<div/>' ).html( attr_val ).text();

                                    // Attach to matching options by value. This is done to compare
                                    // TEXT values rather than any HTML entities.
                                    var $option_elements = new_attr_select.find( 'option' );
                                    if ( $option_elements.length ) {
                                        for (var i = 0, len = $option_elements.length; i < len; i++) {
                                            var $option_element = $( $option_elements[i] ),
                                                option_value = $option_element.val();

                                            if ( attr_val === option_value ) {
                                                $option_element.addClass( 'attached ' + variation_active );
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // Attach all apart from placeholder.
                                    new_attr_select.find( 'option:gt(0)' ).addClass( 'attached ' + variation_active );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Count available options.
            attached_options_count = new_attr_select.find( 'option.attached' ).length;

            // Check if current selection is in attached options.
            if ( selected_attr_val ) {
                selected_attr_val_valid = false;

                if ( 0 !== attached_options_count ) {
                    new_attr_select.find( 'option.attached.enabled' ).each( function() {
                        var option_value = $( this ).val();

                        if ( selected_attr_val === option_value ) {
                            selected_attr_val_valid = true;
                            return false; // break.
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            // Detach the placeholder if:
            // - Valid options exist.
            // - The current selection is non-empty.
            // - The current selection is valid.
            // - Placeholders are not set to be permanently visible.
            if ( attached_options_count > 0 && selected_attr_val && selected_attr_val_valid && ( 'no' === show_option_none ) ) {
                new_attr_select.find( 'option:first' ).remove();
                option_gt_filter = '';
            }

            // Detach unattached.
            new_attr_select.find( 'option' + option_gt_filter + ':not(.attached)' ).remove();

            // Finally, copy to DOM and set value.
            current_attr_select.html( new_attr_select.html() );
            current_attr_select.find( 'option' + option_gt_filter + ':not(.enabled)' ).prop( 'disabled', true );

            // Choose selected value.
            if ( selected_attr_val ) {
                // If the previously selected value is no longer available, fall back to the placeholder (it's going to be there).
                if ( selected_attr_val_valid ) {
                    current_attr_select.val( selected_attr_val );
                } else {
                    current_attr_select.val( '' ).trigger( 'change' );
                }
            } else {
                current_attr_select.val( '' ); // No change event to prevent infinite loop.
            }
        });

        // Custom event for when variations have been updated.
        form.$form.trigger( 'woocommerce_update_variation_values' );
    };

    /**
     * Get chosen attributes from form.
     * @return array
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.getChosenAttributes = function() {
        var data   = {};
        var count  = 0;
        var chosen = 0;

        this.$attributeFields.each( function() {
            var attribute_name = $( this ).data( 'attribute_name' ) || $( this ).attr( 'name' );
            var value          = $( this ).val() || '';

            if ( value.length > 0 ) {
                chosen ++;
            }

            count ++;
            data[ attribute_name ] = value;
        });

        return {
            'count'      : count,
            'chosenCount': chosen,
            'data'       : data
        };
    };

    /**
     * Find matching variations for attributes.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.findMatchingVariations = function( variations, attributes ) {
        var matching = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < variations.length; i++ ) {
            var variation = variations[i];

            if ( this.isMatch( variation.attributes, attributes ) ) {
                matching.push( variation );
            }
        }
        return matching;
    };

    /**
     * See if attributes match.
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.isMatch = function( variation_attributes, attributes ) {
        var match = true;
        for ( var attr_name in variation_attributes ) {
            if ( variation_attributes.hasOwnProperty( attr_name ) ) {
                var val1 = variation_attributes[ attr_name ];
                var val2 = attributes[ attr_name ];
                if ( val1 !== undefined && val2 !== undefined && val1.length !== 0 && val2.length !== 0 && val1 !== val2 ) {
                    match = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return match;
    };

    /**
     * Show or hide the reset link.
     */
    VariationForm.prototype.toggleResetLink = function( on ) {
        if ( on ) {
            if ( this.$resetVariations.css( 'visibility' ) === 'hidden' ) {
                this.$resetVariations.css( 'visibility', 'visible' ).hide().fadeIn();
            }
        } else {
            this.$resetVariations.css( 'visibility', 'hidden' );
        }
    };

    /**
     * Function to call wc_variation_form on jquery selector.
     */
    $.fn.wc_variation_form = function() {
        new VariationForm( this );
        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Stores the default text for an element so it can be reset later
     */
    $.fn.wc_set_content = function( content ) {
        if ( undefined === this.attr( 'data-o_content' ) ) {
            this.attr( 'data-o_content', this.text() );
        }
        this.text( content );
    };

    /**
     * Stores the default text for an element so it can be reset later
     */
    $.fn.wc_reset_content = function() {
        if ( undefined !== this.attr( 'data-o_content' ) ) {
            this.text( this.attr( 'data-o_content' ) );
        }
    };

    /**
     * Stores a default attribute for an element so it can be reset later
     */
    $.fn.wc_set_variation_attr = function( attr, value ) {
        if ( undefined === this.attr( 'data-o_' + attr ) ) {
            this.attr( 'data-o_' + attr, ( ! this.attr( attr ) ) ? '' : this.attr( attr ) );
        }
        if ( false === value ) {
            this.removeAttr( attr );
        } else {
            this.attr( attr, value );
        }
    };

    /**
     * Reset a default attribute for an element so it can be reset later
     */
    $.fn.wc_reset_variation_attr = function( attr ) {
        if ( undefined !== this.attr( 'data-o_' + attr ) ) {
            this.attr( attr, this.attr( 'data-o_' + attr ) );
        }
    };

    /**
     * Sets product images for the chosen variation
     */
    $.fn.wc_variations_image_update = function( variation ) {

        var $form             = this,
            $product          = $form.closest( '.product' ),

            $product_gallery  = $product.find( '.images' ),
            $gallery_nav      = $product.find( '.flex-control-nav' ),
            $gallery_img      = $gallery_nav.find( 'li:eq(0) img' ),
            $product_img_wrap = $product
                .find( '.woocommerce-product-gallery__image, .woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder, .woocommerce-loop-product__link' )
                .eq( 0 ),
            $product_img      = $product_img_wrap.find( '.wp-post-image' ),
            $product_link     = $product_img_wrap.find( 'a' ).eq( 0 );

        if ( variation && variation.image && variation.image.src && variation.image.src.length > 1 ) {
            // See if the gallery has an image with the same original src as the image we want to switch to.
            var galleryHasImage = $gallery_nav.find( 'li img[data-o_src="' + variation.image.gallery_thumbnail_src + '"]' ).length > 0;

            // If the gallery has the image, reset the images. We'll scroll to the correct one.
            if ( galleryHasImage ) {
                $form.wc_variations_image_reset();
            }

            // See if gallery has a matching image we can slide to.
            var slideToImage = $gallery_nav.find( 'li img[src="' + variation.image.gallery_thumbnail_src + '"]' );

            if ( slideToImage.length > 0 ) {
                slideToImage.trigger( 'click' );
                $form.attr( 'current-image', variation.image_id );
                window.setTimeout( function() {
                    $( window ).trigger( 'resize' );
                    $product_gallery.trigger( 'woocommerce_gallery_init_zoom' );
                }, 20 );
                return;
            }

            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'src', variation.image.src );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'height', variation.image.src_h );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'width', variation.image.src_w );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'srcset', variation.image.srcset );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'sizes', variation.image.sizes );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'title', variation.image.title );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'data-caption', variation.image.caption );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'alt', variation.image.alt );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'data-src', variation.image.full_src );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'data-large_image', variation.image.full_src );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'data-large_image_width', variation.image.full_src_w );
            $product_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'data-large_image_height', variation.image.full_src_h );
            $product_img_wrap.wc_set_variation_attr( 'data-thumb', variation.image.src );
            $gallery_img.wc_set_variation_attr( 'src', variation.image.gallery_thumbnail_src );
            $product_link.wc_set_variation_attr( 'href', variation.image.full_src );
        } else {
            $form.wc_variations_image_reset();
        }

        window.setTimeout( function() {
            $( window ).trigger( 'resize' );
            $product_gallery.trigger( 'woocommerce_gallery_init_zoom' );
        }, 20 );
    };

    /**
     * Reset main image to defaults.
     */
    $.fn.wc_variations_image_reset = function() {
        var $form             = this,
            $product          = $form.closest( '.product' ),
            $product_gallery  = $product.find( '.images' ),
            $gallery_nav      = $product.find( '.flex-control-nav' ),
            $gallery_img      = $gallery_nav.find( 'li:eq(0) img' ),
            $product_img_wrap = $product
                .find( '.woocommerce-product-gallery__image, .woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder, .woocommerce-loop-product__link' )
                .eq( 0 ),
            $product_img      = $product_img_wrap.find( '.wp-post-image' ),
            $product_link     = $product_img_wrap.find( 'a' ).eq( 0 );

        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'src' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'width' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'height' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'srcset' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'sizes' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'title' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'data-caption' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'alt' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'data-src' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'data-large_image' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'data-large_image_width' );
        $product_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'data-large_image_height' );
        $product_img_wrap.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'data-thumb' );
        $gallery_img.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'src' );
        $product_link.wc_reset_variation_attr( 'href' );
    };

    $(function() {
        if ( typeof wc_add_to_cart_variation_params !== 'undefined' ) {
            $( '.variations_form' ).each( function() {
                $( this ).wc_variation_form();
            });
        }
    });

    /**
     * Avoids using wp.template where possible in order to be CSP compliant.
     * wp.template uses internally eval().
     * @param {string} templateId
     * @return {Function}
     */
    var wp_template = function( templateId ) {
        var html = document.getElementById( 'tmpl-' + templateId ).textContent;
        var hard = false;
        // any <# #> interpolate (evaluate).
        hard = hard || /<#\s?data\./.test( html );
        // any data that is NOT data.variation.
        hard = hard || /{{{?\s?data\.(?!variation\.).+}}}?/.test( html );
        // any data access deeper than 1 level e.g.
        // data.variation.object.item
        // data.variation.object['item']
        // data.variation.array[0]
        hard = hard || /{{{?\s?data\.variation\.[\w-]*[^\s}]/.test ( html );
        if ( hard ) {
            return wp.template( templateId );
        }
        return function template ( data ) {
            var variation = data.variation || {};
            return html.replace( /({{{?)\s?data\.variation\.([\w-]*)\s?(}}}?)/g, function( _, open, key, close ) {
                // Error in the format, ignore.
                if ( open.length !== close.length ) {
                    return '';
                }
                var replacement = variation[ key ] || '';
                // {{{ }}} => interpolate (unescaped).
                // {{  }}  => interpolate (escaped).
                // https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.template
                if ( open.length === 2 ) {
                    return window.escape( replacement );
                }
                return replacement;
            });
        };
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]